# Why is std::iterator deprecated?

Tags: c++, c++17

Template class [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) is set to be deprecated in C++17.  Why so?  It has been a handy way to make sure [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) works, especially if you can make use of the default template arguments.  Is there some other way of doing it in C++17?

Comment: Yes, there's a handy way of doing the same thing in C++17: you just _do the same thing_. "Deprecated" means **only** that it **might** go away in the future. It doesn't mean that you can't use it, or that it won't do what it always did.

Comment: @PeteBecker: But the question is, if it is deprecated, then why would programmers use it when it *might* go away in the next version or so? Why is it deprecated to begin with, if it was so handy?

Comment: @Nawaz -- that gets the question backwards. If it's in the standard, why wouldn't you use it? **Anything** in the standard can, potentially, go away in the future. Yes, something that's deprecated might be more likely to go away, or maybe not; consider the C headers, which are deprecated in C++ but, as a practical matter, will never go away.

Comment: See also: [Preparation for std::iterator Being Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031805/preparation-for-stditerator-being-deprecated)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From [the proposal that suggested its deprecation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r1.html#2.1):

> As an aid to writing iterator classes, the original standard library supplied the iterator class template to automate the declaration of the five typedefs expected of every iterator by iterator_traits. This was then used in the library itself, for instance in the specification of `std::ostream_iterator`:
>
> ```
> template <class T, class charT = char, class traits = char_traits<charT> >
> class ostream_iterator:
>   public iterator<output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>;
> ```
>
> The long sequence of `void` arguments is much less clear to the reader than simply providing the expected typedefs in the class definition itself, which is the approach taken by the current working draft, following the pattern set in C++14 where we deprecated the derivation throughout the library of functors from `unary_function` and `binary_function`.
>
> In addition to the reduced clarity, the iterator template also lays a trap for the unwary, as in typical usage it will be a dependent base class, which means it will not be looking into during name lookup from within the class or its member functions. This leads to surprised users trying to understand why the following simple usage does not work:
>
> ```
> #include <iterator>
>
> template <typename T>
> struct MyIterator : std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T> {
>    value_type data;  // Error: value_type is not found by name lookup 
>
>    // ... implementations details elided ...
> };
> ```
>
> The reason of clarity alone was sufficient to persuade the LWG to update the standard library specification to no longer mandate the standard iterator adapators as deriving from `std::iterator`, so there is no further use of this template within the standard itself. Therefore, it looks like a strong candidate for deprecation.

You can also see STL's reasoning in [LWG 2438](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2438). (h/t [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268146/why-is-stditerator-deprecated/43268283?noredirect=1#comment73639904_43268283))

---

As for some other way of doing it, not really. You could basically implement your own version of `std::iterator` (which isn't too hard) or manually write out all of those typedefs (which isn't too hard either, and I actually prefer it for clarity).

Comment: STL's argument in [LWG 2438](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2438) seems to be sound as well: the name might mislead users (especially from *ahem* certain other programming languages) into thinking that derivation is mandatory, or that writing a function accepting a `std::iterator` is meaningful.

Comment: Why value_type cannot be found by Derived class?

Comment: @Gerard097 Names in a dependent base class are not considered in unqualified look up.  Consider this: `value_type* x;`  Is this a declaration of a pointer or a multiplication expression statement?  If dependent base classes were to be considered, then the answer cannot be determined until instantiation.

Comment: An example for manually writing the required 5 typedefs can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38103394/2085626).

Answer (score 9):

As Barry states, the working group has decided that explicitly declaring the types in the class is more readable and leads to less surprises than inheriting from `std::iterator`.

It's not too hard, though, to convert to the explicit types (below example taken from [www.fluentcpp.com](http://www.fluentcpp.com) [here](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/05/08/std-iterator-deprecated/)). Given a class that was declared like so:

```
class MyIterator
  : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, int, int, int*, int&>
{
  ...
```

The class without `std::iterator` becomes:

```
class MyIterator
{
public:
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = int;
    using difference_type = int;
    using pointer = int*;
    using reference = int&;

    // ...
```