# How to correctly define a partial specialization for a member struct of a templated class?

Tags: visual-studio, templates, c++17, partial-specialization

I am getting an error when trying to add std::iterator_traits for a templated member struct - i.e. I have an iterator class which is a member of a templated outer class:

```
namespace Toolbox {
    template <typename CharType>
    class substring_container_adapter
    {
    public:
        struct iterator // : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, const CharType *>   C++ 17 is very upset at this approach!
        {
            // iterator constructor
            iterator(const CharType * pszPosition, const CharType * pszDelimeters)
```

Later, I try to add a partial specialization for iterator traits to std because apparently inheriting from std::iterator is deprecated (even though that - or boost::iterator_adaptor<> makes perfect sense and actually works in this and other contexts)...

```
// define iterator traits for our custom iterators
namespace std 
{
    template <typename CharType>
    struct iterator_traits<class Toolbox::substring_container_adapter<CharType>::iterator>
    {
        using iterator_category = forward_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = CharType;
    };
}
```

However, VC++ 2017 version 15.7.3 (C++ 17 enabled for this project) complains:

> error C2764: 'CharType': template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization 'std::iterator_traits::iterator>'

Why not?

I suspect that this is !@#$ annoying limitation due to trying to partially specialize a member struct instead of a templated struct outside of substring_container_adapter<>?

Comment: [partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) I think you've just miss added `class` keyword into `struct iterator_traits<class Toolbox:: ...`

Comment: And you don't need those partial template specialization at all :) since [ForwardIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator)

Comment: FWIW - adding more `typename` specifiers doesn't change things (in VS 2017) - same error results.  Seems like it is basic lack of language that it cannot handle this construct of partial spec for an inner class of a template (but I'm hoping someone can clarify this here)

Comment: @VictorGubin I don't see how that helps (yet) - since Concepts are *still* not a part of the language.

Comment: Note that you need all 5 aliases to be a proper `std::iterator_traits`, so you don't gain anything there.

Answer (score 2):

The correct thing to do here is to put the type aliases in `iterator`, rather than try to partially specialize `std::iterator_traits`.

```
namespace Toolbox {
    template <typename CharType>
    class substring_container_adapter
    {
    public:
        struct iterator // : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, const CharType *>   C++ 17 is very upset at this approach!
        {
            using iterator_category = forward_iterator_tag;
            using value_type = const CharType *;
            using reference = const CharType * &;
            using pointer = const CharType * *;
            using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

            // iterator constructor
            iterator(value_type pszPosition, value_type pszDelimeters)

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

A main reason for deprecating `std::iterator` is that the committee disliked the impression that it gave, that all `Iterators` should derive from it, as none of the container iterators are required to. You can define an exact replacement

```
namespace not_std {
  template<class Category, class T, class Distance = ptrdiff_t,
           class Pointer = T*, class Reference = T&>
  struct iterator {
    using iterator_category = Category;
    using value_type        = T;
    using difference_type   = Distance;
    using pointer           = Pointer;
    using reference         = Reference;
  };
}
```

Comment: That looks entirely reasonable.  But why is this preferred (beyond "it works!" ;)  I really want to declare that my iterator class is a type of iterator, rather than having to specify things piecemeal (just feels wrong or arbitrary)

Comment: The above, by the way, is effectively what I get if I inherit from `boost::iterator_adaptor<>` which I was doing previously due to the above limitations and no analog in `std`

Comment: have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268146/why-is-stditerator-deprecated)

Comment: Thanks.  That's their reasoning - and I just personally think it kind of sucks.  Just as my previous comment - it's just this arbitrary set of using declarations with no rhyme nor reason (except in the minutia we all have to tuck away on behalf of c++ and the standard bodies idiosyncrasies - blech!) Not dissing you - and I appreciate the clarity of knowing "why" - but I'll state for the record "that's dumb" (purely IMO). ;)

Comment: This is a perfectly fine work-around.  I'll probably mark it as the answer.  But I'm hoping someone will clarify what limitation exists in c++17 that makes it impossible to do the partial specialization for std::iterator_traits for an inner type of a template.

Comment: When I attempt to actually use your suggested solution, I still get compiler errors (in debug) : `xutility(1120): error C2938: '_Iter_cat_t<Toolbox::substring_container_adapter<wchar_t>::iterator>' : Failed to specialize alias template` --- I'm guessing that the fact that this is an embedded type flummoxed the traits partial specialization and failed to resolve to the public `using iterator_category` I 2x the spelling!