# C++ iterator to string-like types

Tags: c++, iterator

The plan is to implement a class with two constructors. The first ctor should take a string-like type, the second ctor two iterators (begin and end) to a container of string-like objects. Internally, the class will work with `const char*`, null-terminated C strings. For the first ctor, that's an easy task where I can just be explicit. Passing in a C++ `string` with `str.c_str()` or similar string-like types works fine. For the second ctor however I'm not so sure how I should implement it. In general, it should be a `LegcayInputIterator` with a value type that is convertible to `const char*`. From the top of my head I can think of at least 4 types I want to support, and overloading the second ctor for so many seems like the wrong approach.

Why does my second ctor fail to compile? The `++`, `!=` and `*` operators should be defined. What would be a working approach to pass in two iterators to `T` but actually allow different string-like types from which I could get `const char*` (see example 5 in the code)?

The example code should illustrate my approach, but doesn't work unfortunately.

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

struct Example {

    using CtorIterator = std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, const char*>;
    Example(const char *text)
    {
        std::printf("Called single argument ctor, text = %s\n", text);
    }

    Example(CtorIterator begin, CtorIterator end)
    {
        std::printf("Called iterator ctor, text = [");
        for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it)
            std::printf("%s, ", *it);
        std::printf("]\n");
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Example ex1("Hello");
    std::string arg2("String");
    Example ex2(arg2.c_str());

    std::vector<const char*> args3{"A", "B", "C"};
    std::array<const char*, 3> args4{"D", "E", "F"};
    std::vector<std::string> args5{"G", "H", "I"};

    Example ex3(args3.begin(), args3.end());
    Example ex4(args4.begin(), args4.end());
    Example ex5(args5.begin(), args5.end()); // won't work

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::iterator` is not meant to be used that way. It was introduced into the library to support user-defined iterators by providing [certain member types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) like `iterator_category` and `value_type`. `std::iterator` is an empty class and taking it by value is [meaningless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). Taking it by reference doesn't make much sense either, because iterators do not have to be derived from it. `std::iterator` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268146/why-is-stditerator-deprecated) since C++17.

`LegcayInputIterator` is not a class, but a collection of requirements a type should satisfy. The type itself is not fixed and should be a template parameter. Since C++20, when [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) will become a language feature, you'll be able to write something like this:

```
template<typename InputIt> requires InputIterator<InputIt>
Example(It begin, It end) { ... }
```

or

```
template<InputIterator InputIt>
Example(It begin, It end) { ... }
```

to check that `InputIt` indeed satisfies the requirements of an input iterator. Here `InputIterator` is a concept, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator#Concept) for a particular example. Until then you simply write:

```
template<typename InputIt>
Example(InputIt begin, InputIt end) { ... }
```

For example, `std::vector`'s constructor from a range `[first, last)` is [declared this way](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
template<class InputIt>
vector(InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Comment: Concepts can't come soon enough, because I really don't want to play a lot with `enable_if` to limit this template ctor to meaningful arguments. However, a second question remains (I edited the original question to make it more clear): Now having an iterator to type T, how would I go about in making sure that I always get a `const char*` out of it?

Comment: @flowit, in your particular example you can write `&(*it)[0]` instead of `*it` to get `const char*` both for `const char*` and `std::string` underlying types. You can also write an iterator adapter that would return such a pointer when `operator*` is called.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way is to use *templates* instead:

```
template<typename IterT>
Example(IterT begin, IterT end) { ... }
```

Your way using `std::iterator<...>` doesn't work because few container iterators actually are of the type `std::iterator<...>`, and doesn't have a conversion operator to it.

Comment: But even if containers would return exactly the iterator I'm using, why does the compiler complain about the operators used not being defined? A `std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T>` should provide increment, inequality, dereferencing, ...

Comment: @flowit, `std::iterator` is a now deprecated struct that [was there](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) to provide member types only for user-defined iterators derived from it.

Answer (score 0):

It does not really address the question of why it does not work, but you could utilize [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end)

```
struct Example {

    Example(const char *text)
    {
        std::printf("Called single argument ctor, text = %s\n", text);
    }

    template<typename T>
    Example(const T &t)
    {

        std::printf("Called iterator ctor, text = [");
        for (auto it = std::begin(t); it != std::end(t); ++it)
            std::printf("%s, ", *it);
        std::printf("]\n");
    }
};
```

For relay completely on the range base for:

```
struct Example {  
    Example(const char *text)
    {
        std::printf("Called single argument ctor, text = %s\n", text);
    }

    template<typename T>
    Example(const T &t)
    {
        std::printf("Called iterator ctor, text = [");
        for (const auto &c : t)
            std::printf("%s, ", c);
        std::printf("]\n");
    }
};
```

Comment: I think that's more a question of style, if I pass in a container or two iterators directly (or with C++20 maybe a range). The latter might be more flexible, so that's why I was going for it in the first place. Concepts probably make it easier to limit that template to actual container types. Right now it's just a whole lot of work.