# What is the design purpose of iterator_traits?

Tags: c++, templates, std

The C++ standard library has both `iterator` and `iterator_traits` templates defined. It seemed that in general, the `iterator_traits` just extracts properties that defined explicitly in `iterator`. If a `iterator_traits` is to be used, one can use the corresponding `iterator` directly. If a specialization of certain type (e.g. `T*`) is required, a specialization of `iterator` could match the requirement. What's the benefit this indirection?

Comment: What's the connection between `T*` and `iterator`? The latter is a deprecated class that you inherit from to get some typedefs; `T*` can't inherit from anything.

Comment: If I have the function `template <typename It> void for_each(It begin, It end)` I don't want to have to write any specializations or boilerplate to convert a `U*` into a `iterator`.  I just want to work with any type of iterator, so I use `iterator_traits` as it takes care of it for me.

Comment: Try to implement template with iterators which will work for any kind of iterator: raw pointers (in c-array) or vector integrator or list iterator, and try get type of pointed item or kind of iterator (random access iterator, sequential iterator).

Comment: Note that `std::iterator` is deprecated in c++17 and shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It seemed that in general, the iterator_traits just extracts properties that defined explicitly in iterator. If a iterator_traits is to be used, one can use the corresponding iterator directly.

Not all iterators can type aliases as members.

> What's the benefit this indirection?

To allow all iterators to have a uniform interface. More specifically, pointers are iterators too and as non-class types, pointers cannot have members.

So, when for example the user of an iterator wants the answer to the question "What is the type of the object pointed by `an_iterator_type`", they cannot use `an_iterator_type::value_type` because that cannot be defined for all iterators - specifically pointers. What they can use is `std::iterator_traits<an_iterator_type>::value_type` which can be defined for all iterators - including pointers. That is the purpose of `std::iterator_traits`.

---

The standard defines the `std::iterator_traits<T*>` specialisations for pointers. Although you can, you don't need to define specialisations for custom iterator types because you can instead define the types as members, which will be used by the generic definition of `std::iterator_traits`.

The intention of `std::iterator` was to be optionally used as a base class to help define the member types for custom iterators. However its use was never necessary, it is considered to be a flawed design and its use has long been discouraged. Since C++17, it has been deprecated and it may be removed from future standards.

An example that hopefully demonstrates the problem of the design of `std::iterator`:

```
// using the deprecated std::iterator
struct iterator : std::iterator<
    std::input_iterator_tag,   // OK so far
    long,                      // can you guess what member this argument defines?
    long,                      // how about this?
    const long*,               // you can probably guess this one
    long>                      // still, no clue
{
    ...

// recommended way without using std::iterator
struct iterator
{
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = long;
    using difference_type = long;
    using pointer = const long*;
    using reference = long;
    ...
```

Comment: As @François Andrieux pointed out, the `iterator template` has been deprecated. I've read some threads. Can I interpret this way: although it was not the root cause of deprecation, there were redundancy between `iterator template` and `iterator_traits template`. Then indirection of `iterator template` had been removed, making the function of `iterator_traits template` more sensible?

Comment: The thread mentioned above:  [Preparation for std::iterator Being Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031805/preparation-for-stditerator-being-deprecated) and [Why is std::iterator deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268146/why-is-stditerator-deprecated)

Comment: @user3059627 `As @ François Andrieux pointed out, the iterator template has been deprecated.` I also mention the deprecation in my answer. `Can I interpret this way: although it was not the root cause of deprecation, there were redundancy between iterator template and iterator_traits template.` No, I wouldn't agree with that interpretation. `Then indirection of iterator template had been removed` It hasn't been removed yet. You can see the latter part of my answer, as well as the accepted answers to the questions you linked. The deprecation has little to do with `std::iterator_traits`.

Comment: Thank you. I've got something. Maybe the question should have been "design purpose of `iterator template`" and it has been being gone.