# Why do algorithms use iterator_traits<T>::value_type instead of iter::value_type?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, iterator-traits

In an algorithm, I can determine the `value_type` directly from the iterator via `iter::value_type`. Why do algorithms use `iterator_traits` to do the same?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template<typename iter>
void for_each(iter first, iter end)
{
    cout << "container value type: "
         << typeid(typename iter::value_type).name()
         << endl;

    cout << "container value type: "
         << typeid(typename iterator_traits<iter>::value_type).name()
         << endl; 
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v1;
    for_each(begin(v1), end(v1));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
container value type: i
container value type: i
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a type `iterator` to be an iterator, it is not necessary to have an `iterator::value_type` alias. For example, every pointer is an iterator, namely a [*ContiguousIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator). The user might write:

```cpp
int data[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
// iterators will be of type int*
for_each(std::begin(data), std::end(data));
```

Your code accepting iterators is expected to work with such a function call. Pointers aren't the only problem though:

[`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) is a very old construct from C++98, and back in those days, you weren't able to obtain information such as the `value_type` of an iterator with `decltype()`, because `decltype` didn't exist. Nowadays, you could write something like:

```cpp
auto value = *it;
// and
using value_type = std::decay_t<decltype(*it)>;
```

for *some* iterators, but not all.

**Be careful**, the `value_type` can be customized in two ways that break the above code:

- your iterator can have an `iterator::value_type` type alias, which `std::iterator_traits` will look for
- you are allowed to define a specialization `std::iterator_traits<iterator>` yourself

Because these customization points exist, **you must always** use `std::iterator_traits` when accessing type information about an iterator. Even in situations where `decltype` or `auto` look okay, your code could be incorrect because `std::iterator_traits` was specialized for the iterator you're working with.

---

See also: [What is the design purpose of iterator_traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738051/5740428)

Comment: A good example of the second part of this answer is the notorious `std::vector<bool>`.  `std::iterator_traits<std::vector<bool>::iterator>::value_type` is `bool`, but `decltype` or `auto` will give you some internal bit reference wrapper type, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 11):

A pointer is a valid iterator type (into an array, for example), but has no `value_type` member. However, `iterator_traits` still works for that pointer type.

Comment: can you add small example here ?

Comment: @HardikSavsaviya Just replace the vector with an array and you will get an error at `iter::value_type`: https://godbolt.org/z/K3o8G8EqY.